# Trigger javascript function when facebook comment left

Tags: javascript, facebook, comments, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook like callback, and post it to target to like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735609/facebook-like-callback-and-post-it-to-target-to-like)

I'm trying to find a way to run a javascript function  when someone leaves a comment on something in my facebook app via the comment pluggin. Is there any way I detect the event. Would also like to a the same when some clicks the "Like" button.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FB.Event.subscribe function.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', function (response) {
    // do something with response
});
```

I haven't tried this out myself, but I've read you should add the `notify="true"` attribute to the `fb:comments` tag for it to work.